# Creating new instance objects

Tags: python, class, object

I'm not sure that I've gotten this right. I'm working on learning Python and I'm wondering how exactly you call the constructor of a class. Currently the class is in it's own module that is imported in the main file. Is it right to go

```
Class.Class(variables, here)
```

Or is there some easier way to go about this?

Comment: "Or is there some easier way to go about this?"  What could possibly be easier?

Comment: @S.Lott It's easy but for instance in java it would just be Class(variables, here)

Comment: I don't see what's dramatically easier about the Java version.  If you used `from module import Class`, the Python would be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create instances like this:

```
import MyMod
obj = MyMod.MyClass(param1, param2)
```

This is the canonical way to instantiate Python objects.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. Alternatively you can do:

```
from Class import Class
Class(variables, here)
```